# How does Facebook URL regex work?

Tags: regex, django

When you are in your profile the url is

```
www.facebook.com/<username>
```

However there are also URLs like

```
www.facebook.com/support

www.facebook.com/help
```

Why does this not conflict with the profile pages? Why does the application not try to find the users `support` or `help` and show an error?

I work in Django and I can assume that these URLs for support and help are listed BEFORE the user profile URL. However, I have projects with multiple apps and the home pages for apps like `accounts` and `admin` will also conflict with the user profile URLs as the URLs will be like

```
127.0.0.1:8000/admin

127.0.0.1:8000/accounts
```

Django will try to find the usernames `admin` and `accounts`. How can I solve this problem in a way that is readable by someone else trying to understand my code?

Comment: Try to document it.

Comment: @revo I didn't understand. Come again?

Answer (score 1):

easy don't let the user get these names, you can create Forbidden username function, so that whenever a user opts for username like admin, accounts give them an error, to get you clear read a part of the code which should be in forms.py and i think thats what facebook uses too!!

```
def ForbiddenUsernamesValidator(value):
    forbidden_usernames = ['admin', 'settings', 'news', 'about', 'help', 'signin', 'signup', 
        'signout', 'terms', 'privacy', 'cookie', 'new', 'login', 'logout', 'administrator', 
        'join', 'account', 'username', 'root', 'blog', 'user', 'users', 'billing', 'subscribe',
        'reviews', 'review', 'blog', 'blogs', 'edit', 'mail', 'email', 'home', 'job', 'jobs', 
        'contribute', 'newsletter', 'shop', 'profile', 'register', 'auth', 'authentication',
        'campaign', 'config', 'delete', 'remove', 'forum', 'forums', 'download', 'downloads', 
        'contact', 'blogs', 'feed', 'faq', 'intranet', 'log', 'registration', 'search', 
        'explore', 'rss', 'support', 'status', 'static', 'media', 'setting', 'css', 'js',
        'follow', 'activity', 'library']
    if value.lower() in forbidden_usernames:
        raise ValidationError('This is a reserved word.')
```

Comment: I think I did not explain my problem clearly. Even if a user does not have `admin` as his username, when loading e.g. `www.mysite.com/admin`, Django thinks that I am trying to load the profile page of a user named `admin`. So in this case, I cannot go to admin panel as Django will load the `Profile` view instead of loading the admin backend page. How can I tell Django not to load user profile page when the URL regex clearly matches the URL for profile page i.e. `url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$',),`?

Comment: make sure that your most ambiguous regex is the latest in the list, it will first try to match the exact URLs, and if it didn't match any of those it'll go on with your username url